# Symfony2.4.1 - Generate controller with actions in one command fails

Tags: symfony

I want to generate a controller with a bunch of actions, but by using only one command.

The command I use:

```
$ php app/console generate:controller --no-interaction --controller=Sample01DemoBundle:Demo1 --actions=helloAction:/hello:Sample01DemoBundle:Demo1:hello.html.twig --route-format=yml --template-format=twig
```

Here's the error output:

```
  Controller generation  


PHP Warning:  Illegal string offset 'name' in /home/rocker/projects/sample01/vendor/sensio/generator-bundle/Sensio/Bundle/GeneratorBundle/Generator/ControllerGenerator.php on line 56
PHP Warning:  Illegal string offset 'basename' in /home/rocker/projects/sample01/vendor/sensio/generator-bundle/Sensio/Bundle/GeneratorBundle/Generator/ControllerGenerator.php on line 56
PHP Warning:  Illegal string offset 'template' in /home/rocker/projects/sample01/vendor/sensio/generator-bundle/Sensio/Bundle/GeneratorBundle/Generator/ControllerGenerator.php on line 61
PHP Notice:  Undefined offset: 2 in /home/rocker/projects/sample01/vendor/sensio/generator-bundle/Sensio/Bundle/GeneratorBundle/Generator/ControllerGenerator.php on line 190
PHP Notice:  Undefined offset: 1 in /home/rocker/projects/sample01/vendor/sensio/generator-bundle/Sensio/Bundle/GeneratorBundle/Generator/ControllerGenerator.php on line 190



  [Twig_Error_Runtime]                                                                                         
  Impossible to access an attribute ("basename") on a string variable ("elloAction:/hello/{id}:Sample01DemoB  
  undle:Demo1:hello.html.twig") in "controller/Template.html.twig.twig" at line 4
```

Additional info:

```
$ php app/console --version
Symfony version 2.4.1 - app/dev/debug
```

What am I doing wrong?
Bundle generation works fine.

Every idea is appareciated. Thanks.

Comment: i'am also getting this error. Did you solve this?

Comment: Nope, not yet. Apparently we're the only ones who get this.

Answer (score 2):

Use quotes for actions argument:

```
--actions="helloAction:/hello:Sample01DemoBundle:Demo1:hello.html.twig"
```

See also:

[**Generating a New Controller**](http://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/SensioGeneratorBundle/commands/generate_controller.html)

**UPD:**

According to [SensioGeneratorBundle](https://github.com/sensiolabs/SensioGeneratorBundle/tree/2.2/Command) github, controller generator is available only since symfony version **2.2.x**. So if you want to use controller generator, you must update your symfony copy.

Comment: What symfony version are you using? 2.1.4?

Comment: @TrevorDonahue your question used to have tag `symfony2.4`, so it confused me a bit. I removed it and updated my answer, check it out.

Comment: oups, sorry Hast. it's actually the other way around. It's 2.4.1, in short, the latest. my bad.